# How to edit persistent store from react-persist during runtime

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

We are using [react-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) and we have created a persistent redux-store during initialization.

We'd like to toggle the persistence state of a reducer through `persistConfig` after initialization (or during runtime).

Is this possible ?

This is how we create our store during initialization:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native
import hardSet from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/hardSet'

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['visibilityFilter'] // navigation will not be persisted
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
    let persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { store, persistor }
}
```